# Android Text Editor

Tags: gratis, android, offline, text-editor, note-taking

I am looking for an Android text editor to replace 920 Text Editor.

***Why?***

- It appears 920 Text Editor may be abandoned.  It has not been updated recently, has been removed from the Google Play Store, and the latest version is not available on F-Droid.

***Requirements***

- Must be able to search for text anywhere in the file (including within large text files).
- Must not require internet access.  If it wants internet access at all, the reason must be disclosed or known.
- Must render and edit FAST!
- Must handle text files that contain thousands of pages (tens of thousands of lines).  Must be able to load a 10MB text file without difficulty.
- Not abandoned.
- Gratis (freeware).
- No ads.

***Preferences (not required)***

- Open-source.
- Ability to invert colors (white on black as well as black on white).

---

**UPDATE:** Well, it's been over four months, and no one has found a recommendation meeting the requirements, so I simplified the requirements, in hopes of receiving one or more suitable recommendations.

Comment: While waiting for the "real answers": [Office Suites and Text Editors](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_office) are listed on my site. Watch out for those having an F-Droid icon along, those are for sure open source (which doesn't mean the others aren't). You can also use [the search](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/search) to exclude unwanted permissions in the result list :) Speaking of "pages and photographs": you didn't mention whether those should be "shown" (WYSIWYG) or just their link. And what file formats you're after (Markdown? HTML?).

Comment: Good questions.  All it needs to do is display text.  No need (or desire) for WYSIWYG.  No need to handle Markdown or HTML either.

Comment: Not tried, but take a look at *Vim Touch* ([F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch) / [Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.momodalo.app.vimtouch)). `vi` is known to match all your requirements, including the preferences. If the similarity in names has a say here, it must scream "take me!" :) // Btw: picked from above linked list :)

Comment: Is [QuickEdit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.rhmsoft.edit&hl=en) not a good option for you?

Comment: Thumbs up Izzy and Firelord - I will take a look at both of those recommendations.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend [Jota Text Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.sblo.pandora.jota&hl=en)

Jota is a text editor designed for a long text file.
It's pronouced as "`i-o-ta`".

**Functions**

> - Support until 1 million characters.
> - Auto-Detect multiple character codes. UTF-8 UTF-16BE UTF-16LE UTF-32BE UTF-32LE WINDOWS-1251 WINDOWS-1252 WINDOWS-1253 WINDOWS-1255
>     SHIFT_JIS ISO-2022-JP ISO-2022-CN ISO-2022-KR ISO-8859-5 ISO-8859-7
>     ISO-8859-8 BIG5 GB18030 EUC-JP EUC-KR EUC-TW IBM855 IBM866 KOI8-R
>     MACCYRILLIC HZ-GB-2312 X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-3412 X-ISO-10646-UCS-4-2143
>     (Whether you can decode or not depends on Android's implementation.)
> - Change character codes.
> - Auto-Detect linebreak code.
> - Change linebreak code.
> - Keep linebreak code until saving a file.
> - Save position of the cursor with file.
> - Save history of recened files.
> - Search/Replace (Support Regular Expression)
> - Text sharing with external application. Mushroom Share (ACTION_SEND) Search (ACTION_SEARCH) Open (ACTION_VIEW) ★Direct Intent : You can
>     launch any one application on menu item.
> - Scroll with Thumb-drag.
> - Scroll with Flick.
> - Undo/Redo
> - Support a Shortcut key with ALT/CTRL Key.
> - Customize colors.
> - Create a shortcut icon on HOME app.
> - Customizable shortcut key bind.
> - Text selector like Gingerbread. (Double tap to select the word , then touch selected area to show marker.)
> - Word wrap ON/OFF and set word wrap width.
> - Set tab width.
> - Viewer Mode.
> - Show Line numbers.
> - Word Counter.
> - Support Landscape Mode correctly.
> - Auto save.
> - Auto Indent.
> - Show Tab/Linebreak.
> - Auto capitalize.
> - you can used as SL4A editor.
> - Customizable Toolbar.
> - Customizable Syntax highlght.
> - Capture Screen shot.
> - Wallpaper customize.
> - Support Android OS 1.6 or later.
> - Support both touch-screen device and qwerty-keyboard device.
> - Forever FREE and NO-AD.

Comment: Thanks! I will take a look at it.  At one point, there was some reason why I didn't use it; I'm not sure what the reason was.  Hopefully whatever reason it was is no longer applicable!

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: I'm pretty sure the reason you didn't like Jota earlier is due to its filesize limitation. In your post you stated 10 MB file capacity as a primary requirement, and Jota has an upper limit of 1 MB stated in its specs, and I've seen users complain of crash events when loading even smaller files. Apparently it can go a little higher than 1 MB in some cases, but one guy who reported that also said that it crashed EVERY time on files of 5 MB or more.

Comment: @RonaldAndersson Thanks! I knew there was a reason, and such a low file size restriction would definitely result in it not working for me.  Thanks again.